# How to communicate with non-Qt threads in a C++ program using Qt networking?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets, networking

I have an inherited **C++** program that relies on a **Qt5** library to communicate with a **TCP/IP server** over a secure socket using **QSsl**.

Communication does happen but I keep on seeing this warning:

```
QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread”.
```

I have checked other related questions here but they are rather old and concern **qt4**.

The program first tries to connect to the server by making a call to:

```
devConnectionHandler::instance().connect( args[0].sval, args[1].sval )
// which internally makes a call to this Qt library method
devResult status = dev_connect( name.c_str(), interface.c_str(), NULL );
```

`dev_connect( name.c_str(), interface.c_str(), NULL )` implementation in the Qt library:

```
    Q_UNUSED(reserved);
    //This is a Qobject that holds the socket object for server communication
    DevHalRemote *hal = new DevHalRemote();
    //This method make the actual connection
    const DevResult result = hal->DevConnect(name, interface);

    if (result == DEV_OK) {
        m_RemoteList.insert(name, hal);
    } else {
        delete hal;
    }

    return result;
```

`DevHalRemote()` implementation:

```
DevHalRemote::DevHalRemote(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    m_socket = new QSslSocket(this);
    m_socket->setProtocol(QSecureSslProtocols);
    m_socket->setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
    m_socket->setProxy(QNetworkProxy::NoProxy);

    if (!QCoreApplication::instance())
        new QCoreApplication(g_argc, g_argv);
}
```

After this connection, the main thread initialize multiple data structure instance to store and configure the device.

Now each of these structures makes a call to the Qt library method:

```
DevItemProperty item = dev_getItemProperty( name, object )
```

which is implemented like this:

```
devItemProperty dev_getItemProperty(const char *name, const char *object)
{
    DevHalRemote *hal = m_halRemoteList.value(name);
    return hal->GetItemProperty(object);
}
```

`DevHalRemote::GetItemProperty` implementation:

```
DevItemProperty DevHalRemote::GetItemProperty(const QByteArray &item)
{
    const QByteArray data = writeRead(DEV_REMOTE_GETPROPERTY, item);
    if (data.isEmpty())
        return DEV_ERROR;

    DevItemProperty result;
    memcpy(&result, data.constData(), sizeof(DevItemProperty));
    return result;
}
```

`devHalRemote::writeRead` implementation:

```
QByteArray DevHalRemote::writeRead(char command, const QByteArray &value) const
{
    QByteArray write = command;
    if (!value.isEmpty())
        write += ';' + value;
    const QByteArray read = writeReadSynchronous(write);
    return read;
}
```

`devHalRemote::writeReadSynchronous` implementation:

```
QByteArray DevHalRemote::writeReadSynchronous(const QByteArray &data) const
{
    m_socket->write(data);
    if (!m_socket->waitForBytesWritten(timeout()))
        return QByteArray();

    m_socket->waitForReadyRead(timeout());
    const QByteArray read = m_socket->readAll();

    QCoreApplication::instance()->processEvents();

    return read;
}
```

After that, the C++ program explicitly creates a `pthread`. This is done because the server is exposed to a web interface through which the device data and configuration can be modified. So, one needs to listen to these changes and update the program data structures.

Within the `run()` method of this `pthread`, this happens:

```
void devHalThread::run() {
  while( true ) {
  // devHal_info_tis a typedef for my data structure
    std::list<devHal_info_t*>::iterator it = _recs.begin();
    if( _pause > 0. ) this->thread.sleep( _pause ); 

    if( !_run ) continue;

    // some "benchmarking"
    struct timespec start;
#ifdef _POSIX_CPUTIME
    clock_gettime( CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &start );
#else
    clock_gettime( CLOCK_MONOTONIX, &start );
#endif
 //printf( "DevHalThread::run: Reading item '%s'\n", (*it)->object );
 
    for( ; it != _recs.end(); ++it ) {
     /* this call is one one giving the warning from QtSocketNotifier*/
      DevItemProperty item = dev_getItemProperty( (*it)->interface, (*it)->object)
      if( strcmp( item.quality, Dev_ITEM_QUALITY_OK ) != 0 ) continue;
        // value was updated in DevHAL
        memcpy( (*it)->value, item.value, VALUE_SIZE );
        (*it)->time = time;
        callbackRequest( (*it)->pcallback );
      }
    }
}
```

This call `DevItemProperty item = dev_getItemProperty( (*it)->interface, (*it)->object)` inside the for loops, access the socket outside the thread it was created and I got this warning.

I found that for communicating with non-qt threads, one needs to use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`.

So inside the `pthread` `run()` I removed  this call

```
DevItemProperty item = dev_getItemProperty( (*it)->interface, (*it)->object)
```

and added this:

```
QString object((*it)->object);
       QMetaObject::invokeMethod(halCon.hal_interface,
                                "devhal_getItem",
                                Qt::DirectConnection,
                                Q_RETURN_ARG(DevItemProperty, item),
                                Q_ARG(QString, object)
                                );
//devCon.hal_interface is an pointer to the devHalRemote object(Qobject) that handle the socket.
devhal_getItem is a method I added to devHalRemote as a slot 
Q_SLOT DevItemProperty devhal_getItem(const QString s);

IsegItem DevItemProperty devhal_getItem(const QString object){
  DevItemProperty item = GetItemProperty(object.toUtf8());
  return item;
}
```

The invocation does work, but the warning still remains, if changed `DirectConnection` to `QueuedConnection`. It seems the thread just freezes, and no update.